# <li> tags are getting stacked while using mmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mmenu

I am using the [mmenu jquery library](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/examples.html) for making a mobile menu on my site. I copy pasted exact implementation code inside my website and mmenu is working but the `<li>` rows inside menu are getting stacked on each other. I believe the css rules of mmenu `<nav>` are inherting some css rules from container div. This stacking up of rows inside menu was even happening when I tried using basic examples as mentioned on mmenu site (my implementation ahead).

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Actual mmenu example can be found [here](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/demo/index.html?demo=menu-style-1)

Screenshot of my implementation:

[image]

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#/">
                <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
                Home
                </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/about">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> 
                About us
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/contact">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> 
                Contact
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#menu").mmenu({
        extensions: [ 
            "theme-black", 
            "effect-menu-zoom", 
            "effect-panels-zoom", 
            "pagedim-black" 
        ],
        navbar: false,
        navbars: {
            height: 4,
            content: [ 
                '<a href="#/" class="fa fa-phone"></a>',
                '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/60/60/people/1/" />',
                '<a href="#/" class="fa fa-envelope"></a>'
            ]
        }
    }).on('click', 'a[href^="#/"]', function() {
        alert("Clicked");
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.mm-menu {
    background: #440011 !important;
}
.mm-navbar {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: none;
}
.mm-navbar:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}
.mm-navbar > * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.mm-navbar img {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    border-radius: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.mm-navbar a {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    border-radius: 40px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) !important;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
}
.mm-navbar a:hover {
    border-color: #fff;
    color: #fff !important;
}
.mm-listview {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.mm-listview li:last-child:after {
    content: none;
    display: none;
}
.mm-listview li:after {
    left: 20px !important;
    right: 20px !important;
}
.mm-listview a {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0 !important;
}
.mm-listview a,
.mm-listview .fa {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.mm-listview a:hover,
.mm-listview a:hover .fa {
    color: #fff;
}
.mm-listview .fa {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
}

html.mm-opened.mm-effect-zoom-menu body
{
    background: #f3f3f3;
}
html.mm-opened.mm-effect-zoom-menu.mm-theme-dark body
{
     background: #333;
}
html.mm-opened.mm-effect-zoom-menu.mm-theme-black body
{
    background: #000;
}
html.mm-opened.mm-effect-zoom-menu.mm-theme-white body
{
    background: #fff;
}
html.mm-opened.mm-effect-zoom-menu .mm-page
{
    background-color: #fff;
}

.mm-menu li .fa
{
    margin: 0 20px 0 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 12px;
}
.mm-menu li[class*="mm-tile"] .fa
{
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}

.mm-menu .buttonbar-item:after
{
    content: none !important;
    display: none !important;
}
```

**Edits**
After removing `position:absolute`  ,as guided in answers ,i am getting `<li>` in single row
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're giving your links the `fa` class, then positioning them absolutely. The container isn't positioned relatively, so they're just reading this from screen.

```
        .mm-listview .fa {
            position: absolute;
            left: 20px;
        }
```

Comment: if i am removing postion:absolute from this css rule , then they are getting visible but only in single row .I need each one of them in different rows

Comment: Then make sure you're positioning your container correctly. i.e. `.mm-listview {position: relative; }`

Comment: i added .mm-listview {position: relative; } and kept .fa links as it is with position:absolute but still am not getting desired result

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle so I can look at exactly what you're trying to achieve and where you're going wrong. Based on what you've posted, most of the classes you're referencing are missing from your HTML code - so I can't really see what's going on in your version.

Comment: i tried to give a jsfiddle example , but there are so many scripts and stylesheets which are being reference , i am editting answer with more css

Comment: It's not the CSS I need, I can't help you if I cannot see your version working, as I dont know what elements are actually in use - therefore unable identify what is being positioned where.

Comment: actually the <nav> tag has css rules which was conflicting with the <li> rules .Thanks i solved the problem and upvoted yours